# Image viewer that shows pixel color value if zoomed enough

Tags: image-viewer

On Windows interface, open a picture, then enlarge the image with mouse, when enlarge to enough big, till display every pixel(pixel is actually a box), meanwhile, within every box, it is show RGB value(color image) or Gray value(gray image).

Constantly enlarging the image and finally displaying the pixel value，how to do? use what software?

Any operating system.